# How do I use a class from a package listed as a dependency in maven?

Tags: java, maven, import, dependencies

New to Java and Maven and having trouble with a dependency. (Not using an IDE)

In the pom.xml for my project I have:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
  <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.1</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

The first build downloaded the dependency and compiled with no errors. But, in MyClass.java, the statement:

```
import org.apache.pdfbox;
```

causes the error:

```
.../MyClass.java:[3,17]error: package org.apache does not exist
```

How do I include maven dependencies in my classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement `import org.apache.pdfbox` is incorrect. You import class(es) from a package, not a package itself. For example,

```
// Import a single class from package pdfbox
import org.apache.pdfbox.SomeClass;
```

or

```
// Import all classes from package pdfbox 
// (But this doesn't import classes from sub-packages)
import org.apache.pdfbox.*;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a class or wildcard in an import statement. Currently you are attempting a class called `pdfbox` which doesn't exist. If you want to import everything in the `pdfbox` package, you can use:

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.*;
```

See Importing in: [Using Package Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is no Class called org.apache.pdfbox, this is a package
You need

```
import  org.apache.pdfbox.*;
```